# How can I install Unity in Kubuntu 12.04?

Tags: unity, installation, 12.04, kubuntu

I'd like to try Unity, but I'm running Kubuntu 12.04 (64-bit). How I can I install the Unity desktop environment?

I tried "sudo apt-get install unity", but after installation and choosing "Gnome" from the login screen, it fails and displays an error dialog saying that the Gnome environment cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 8):

Use `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: I did try this but it didn't work for me. It did work, but  I wasn't able to see login screen (however I could type password and press Enter), some error messages appear, background was changing as system wanted, etc...  So, I installed fresh Ubuntu 15.10 Unity. Kubuntu is great system as well, but I could get used to it.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this question was asked for an earlier version of Kubuntu. However, for those who come via google, the following command is enough to install Unity on Kubuntu 14.04, and is preferable to installing `ubuntu-desktop`:

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: Is there any problems expected by doing this? I have KUbuntu 15.10 and I would like to install Unity.

Comment: @LjiljanVeselinovic: No problems, I actually just did this a few days ago on Kubuntu 15.10. In the end, though, I did install all of `ubuntu-desktop` though it was late and I don't remember why.

Comment: so at the beginning (login such as http://linuxbsdos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/KubuntuLogin-600x450.png) I will have a chance to select Unity? I am just afraid that some packages will be missing and the Unity won't work correctly.

Comment: Correct. "Plasma" is KDE, and "Failsafe" doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I installed ubuntu-desktop, but I cannot login.